# Django - ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'allauth'

Tags: django

I've follow the documentation in "django-allauth"

But I got these errors:

```
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1004, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'allauth'
```

Below is my settings.py
I also re-install the allauth  Requirement already satisfied: pycparser in ./env/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from cffi>=1.12->cryptography>=3.3.1->pyjwt[crypto]>=1.7->django-allauth) (2.21)

But still the same error I get

```
"""
Django settings for config project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 4.0.2.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/
"""

from pathlib import Path

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'django-insecure--!bydo4n0km'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.sites', # associating functionality to 3rd-party site like allauth
    'core', # register your app
    'allauth',
    'allauth.account',
    'allauth.socialaccount',
    'allauth.socialaccount.providers.google',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'config.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = [
    # Needed to login by username in Django admin, regardless of `allauth`
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
    # `allauth` specific authentication methods, such as login by e-mail
    'allauth.account.auth_backends.AuthenticationBackend',
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'config.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = 'static/'

SITE_ID = 1
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/'
# Provider specific settings
SOCIALACCOUNT_PROVIDERS = {
    'google': {
        # For each OAuth based provider, either add a ``SocialApp``
        # (``socialaccount`` app) containing the required client
        # credentials, or list them here:
        'APP': {
            'client_id': '123',
            'secret': '456',
            'key': ''
        }
    }
}
# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/#default-auto-field

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
```

==END of setting.py ==

my requirements.txt

```
asgiref==3.5.0
certifi==2021.10.8
cffi==1.15.0
charset-normalizer==2.0.12
cryptography==36.0.2
defusedxml==0.7.1
Django==4.0.3
django-allauth==0.50.0
idna==3.3
oauthlib==3.2.0
pycparser==2.21
PyJWT==2.3.0
python3-openid==3.2.0
requests==2.27.1
requests-oauthlib==1.3.1
sqlparse==0.4.2
urllib3==1.26.9
```

Comment: Did you install it?

Comment: If so, can you show us your `settings.py`?

Comment: Which python do you use? What is the result of `which python` ?

Comment: I used Python 3.10.2 > python: aliased to /usr/local/bin/python3

Comment: If that is the path you get after `which python`, you are not running python in a virtual environment.  Do you not use virtual environment for your pip installs?

Comment: I did (env) ➜  devph.io git:(main) ✗ pip install [package]

Comment: Actually, I think the problem is that your python is aliased to the absolute path /usr/local/bin/python3. I have mine aliased to `python3` - not including the path. 
Is this aliased in your .bashrc? Try to remove it from your .rc file - source it and run `unalias python`.

Comment: it's in .zshrc `alias python="/usr/local/bin/python3"`

Comment: Hey ErikR, thanks bro it really works! thank you!

Comment: Superb, nice to hear that it solved it. I added the solution as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the python that is running Django does not find the package.

This may be often be because the python that is running is not the one you expect.

Eg. if `which python` returns:

```
python: aliased to /usr/local/bin/python3
```

That will mean every command you run with python (f.x. `python manage.py runserver`), will use that specific python, and that one is not aware of the pip installs you have done in a virtual environment.

If `which python` returns something other than `python3`, you probably should clean out the aliasing in your .bashrc, or not use absolute paths.

To unalias, you can use this command:

```
unalias python
```

Aliasing will of course return if you have specifically aliasing in your .bashrc:

If you have this line in your file (or something similar):

```
python="/usr/local/bin/python3"
```

Remove it, or change it to:

```
python=python3
```